# Having \"{a} in Doxygen, LaTeX

Tags: encoding, latex, doxygen

**How can you make this `\"{a}` to present *a with dots* in Doxygen?**

My files are full of the character \"{a}.
It should be universal encoding for *a with dots*. However, it is clearly not the case.
My encoding is UTF-8 at the moment. The symbol works with the encoding in Vim.

Comment: I've never seen that character encoding form before.  I don't recognize it as a Unicode escape.  What is this "universal encoding" of which you speak?  Are you sure it's not a Vim-specific encoding?

Comment: \"{a} is the LaTeX encoding for ä.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a compelling reason for using that particular escape for [a-with-an-umlaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84), I suggest that you simply replace all occurrences with the actual character "ä" (Unicode code point U+00E4).

Comment: **How can you make this replacement safely?** It seems to be a task for `tr`. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: You're in the Unix world, and I can't help you there. I assume that there are plenty of global find-and-replace tools available to you; I'd simply replace the literal (not regex) *\"{a}* with *ä* in any files that could contain that escape.  Review a sampling of the results.  I don't know LaTeX, and I could see that there could be a risk there - the LaTeX world might have a solution.

Comment: If you're using vim, you should be able to do something like `:%s/\\"{a}/ä/g`. There aren't any wildcards here so it's a pretty safe search and replace, but if you want to do a little testing, you can use `:%s/\\"{a}/ä/gc`, which will let you say yes or no to each substitution.

Comment: Oh, and if you need to do this in multiple files, have a look at the `bufdo` and `windo` commands, which can apply a command to all open buffers or windows. If you want to do this from command-line/script, try `sed` (not `tr`, which works only on single characters). Something like `sed 's/\\"{a}/ä/g' <files>` should work, and then you can add the `-i` option once you know it's doing the right thing to have it edit the files in place.

Comment: Perl is finally the rigth tool. This solves the problem `perl -i.bak -pe 's@hello@@'`